# ESLint react-hooks - 'exhaustive-deps' rule - is there really no better way?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

There is quite a lot of information about this rule, but I really think that there should be made some better way to handle the componentDidMount-alternative.

It looks that it confuses also a lot of developers and it is quite difficult to write work-arounds for the most common use-cases:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920

Here I provide few examples that really are not easy to be set-up with this rule:

**Example 1**: Initialization of app - or check cookies/localstorage once the application loads, and set them in the context:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import CookieHandler from '../helpers/CookieHandler';
import Loading from '../components/common/Loading';

const defaultValues = {
  authorization: {
    loggedIn: false,
    isAdmin: false,
  },
  dispatchAuthorization: () => {},
};

const LoginContext = createContext(defaultValues);

const reducer = (state, authorization = { loggedIn: false, isAdmin: false }) => {
  const { loggedIn, isAdmin } = authorization;
  return { loggedIn: !!loggedIn, isAdmin: !!isAdmin };
};

const LoginContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authorization, dispatchAuthorization] = React.useReducer(reducer, defaultValues.authorization);
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  const setLoginData = (token, isAdmin) => {
    if (token) {
      dispatchAuthorization({
        loggedIn: true,
        isAdmin: isAdmin,
      });
    }
    setMounted(true);
  };

  const setLanguage = (language) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(language);
    CookieHandler.setLanguage(language);
  };

  const loginUser = data => {
    CookieHandler.setToken(data.token);
    CookieHandler.setAdmin(data.isAdmin);
    setLoginData(data.token, data.isAdmin);
  };

  const removeLoginData = () => {
    CookieHandler.logout();
    dispatchAuthorization({
      loggedIn: false,
      isAdmin: false,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = CookieHandler.getToken();
    const isAdmin = CookieHandler.getAdmin();
    const language = CookieHandler.getLanguage();

    if (token) {
      setLoginData(token, isAdmin);
    } else if (authorization.loggedIn || authorization.isAdmin) removeLoginData();

    if (language) setLanguage(language);
    setMounted(true);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) return <Loading />;

  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider
      value={{
        authorization,
        dispatchAuthorization,
        setLoginData,
        loginUser,
        setLanguage,
        logoutUser: removeLoginData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
};

const LoginContextConsumer = LoginContext.Consumer;

export { LoginContext, LoginContextProvider, LoginContextConsumer };
```

Here I want that the `useEffect` is called really **once** the application is loaded, and never again. But according to eslint I should add the authorization variable in the dept array, but that is something I really don't want to do. Because each time there is a change in the authorization, the whole INIT-Prozess will start over and over again. I think an init-functionality that fires once the component/or application starts is quite needed, without thinking of changing in variables later?

**Example 2:** Use of functions that are comming from hooks. An example with **react-i18next**:

```
...
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
...

const MyComponent = ({ someId }) => {
 const { t } = useTranslation();
 const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const someAsyncFetch = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await asyncFetchData({
      someId,
    });
    setData(data);
    toastr.success(t('your.data.was.fetched.successfully'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    toastr.error(t('your.data.can.not.be.fetched'));
  }
 };
    someAsyncFetch();
  }, [someId]);
}
```

In this example, I want to get all the data when my component gets rendered, or when the someId is changed. When data is loaded or error comes - I fire toastr message with the translation function **t** that I get in a hook. But I don't want to get new data each time the user switch his language. But eslint want me to put t in the deps array, which causes to re-render component and load new data each time the user switch the language. And moreover, we should expect that more and more such hook-functions will come in future, which we eventually may want to use in the useEffects.

**Example 3:** One variable is depending on other variables

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error === null) {
      const data = doSomethingWithMyValue(value1);
      setMyData(data);
    } else {
      showSomeErrorText(); //or do nothing
    }
  }, [value1]);
```

If I want that only when value1 changes, the function doSomethingWithMyValue will be fired, but not when error changes. When we put error inside the `useEffects` deps array then the whole logic is broken, because useEffect will be fired each time error changes. And this is something I don't want.

I tried also to make some kind of workaround with a mounted variable, and `useCallback`, but it looks for me that `useEffect` fires unnecessary many times, and somehow the whole thing is slower.

So is there somewhere a logic-catch or we really need to use all this memo and `useCallbacks` etc. to prevent some serious issue?

Thanks for any feedback!